# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, oop, fatal-error

here is the part if having error.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
>   object context in
>   /pb_events.php
>   on line 6

line 6 is:     `$jpp = $this->vars->data["jpp"];`

```
function DoEvents($this) {

    global $_CONF, $_PAGE, $_TSM , $base;

    $jpp = $this->vars->data["jpp"];

    $cache["departments"] = $this->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$this->tables[job_departments]}");
    $cache["locations"] = $this->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$this->tables[job_location]}");
    $cache["names"] = $this->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$this->tables[job_names]}");
    $cache["categories"] = $this->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$this->tables[job_categories]}");
```

Thanks a lot! appreciate!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$this only makes sense in methods, not in functions

this is ok

```
class Foo {
     function bar() {
          $this->...
```

this is not

```
function some() {
    $this->
```

// edit: didn't notice he passes "$this" as parameter

advice: simply replace "$this" with "$somethingElse"

Comment: thanks for reply! this is an opensource softwares code which was working well on PHP4. now i try on PHP5 and has errors :/ I'm not very good at php :/ trying to sort out the issue according to your advise...

Comment: so how can i edit this? :/ if i put a class on top, the other pages are not working... big mess

Comment: wowowowow man!! I LOVE YOU@@@@!!!! LIFE SAVER!!!! THANKS A LOT MAN!! :) )woaaaa so happy!!

Comment: You will also get this error if you use self::bar() even inside Foo.

Comment: You will also get this error if you declare you method as static. All static methods are considered to be called outside the class scope

Answer (score 7):

You cannot pass `$this` to a procedural function. `$this` is a reserved variable.

Comment: hey, thanks! so what is your advise for solution? can you be a bit more clear? Im not very good at php :/

Comment: just change the name of the variable passed. check my answer.

Comment: Michael is absolutely correct. Just change the name of the variable.

Answer (score 5):

As per my comments.
You want to use `$this` as passed variable and php doesn't allow it outside class methods body.

```
function DoEvents($obj) {

    global $_CONF, $_PAGE, $_TSM , $base;

    $jpp = $obj->vars->data["jpp"];

    $cache["departments"] = $obj->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$obj->tables[job_departments]}");
    $cache["locations"] = $obj->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$obj->tables[job_location]}");
    $cache["names"] = $obj->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$obj->tables[job_names]}");
    $cache["categories"] = $obj->db->QFetchRowArray("SELECT * FROM {$obj->tables[job_categories]}");
```

Comment: yes ! thats the issue! how silly im! sorted just before your comment... you life saver too!! thanks a lot!!! super you guys are!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the object first.

```
   $object=new Myobject;
   DoEvents($object);
```