# Php Mysql Database query error

Tags: php

Basically, from the form that I made I send `customer_name` and with this code I pull it and save it to the database along with the time. This code keeps giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/projectu/public_html/sub/save.php on line 19

Note: 19th line is this one:

```
$db->query($queryone);
```

Here is my code:

Whole Save.php

```
include('db-config.php');

$customer_name = $_POST['customername'];

/* Kaspersky */
$kaspersky_date = strtotime("+11 months").'|'.strtotime("+12 months");
$kaspersky = explode("|", $kaspersky_date);
$kaspersky_temp = "$customer_name got new kaspersky.";

/* PC Picked-UP */
$pickedups_date = strtotime("+1 months");
$pickedups_temp = "$customer_name picked up his computer.";


if(isset($_POST['kaspersky'])) {
$queryone = "INSERT INTO sublist (scheduled_date, customer_name, kaspersky_status, kaspersky_template)
                       VALUES ($kaspersky[0], $customer_name, YES, $kaspersky_temp)";

$this->query($queryone);

$querytwo = "INSERT INTO sublist (scheduled_date, customer_name, kaspersky_status, kaspersky_template)
                       VALUES ($kaspersky[1], $customer_name, YES, $kaspersky_temp)";

$this->query($querytwo);

}
if(isset($_POST['pickeduppc'])) {
$query = "INSERT INTO sublist (scheduled_date, customer_name, pcpickup_status, pcpickup_template)
                       VALUES ($pickedups_date, $customer_name, YES, $pickedups_temp)";
}
```

Comment: `$this` can only be used within object methods. It will fail if used outside of an object.

Comment: So what is the value of $db; and what is the query method on that object?

Comment: All I want to do is to run the insert query. how do I do that? To connect the database I used mysqli

Comment: This code isn't the one generating the error. There's no `$this` in this code. Please give us the relevant piece of code.

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the right file? doesnt look right to me

Comment: I coded this page. I did not put $this in it. Do I have to?

Comment: @Mike B. I haven't coded PHP for 3 years so I forgot a lot of it sorry and thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Show us the code in save.php

Comment: You have a typo `$kaskersky_date`

Comment: @Extelliqent What is the code in `db-config.php`? Regardless, `$this` is a magic variable name reserved for use in an object instance context only. You cannot use it in a procedural script like the above. You need to look at exactly how you are creating your MySQLi object and how you are passing it into the above script.

Comment: db-config.php

$host = "localhost";
$name = "projectu_subscription";
$user = "projectu_subuser";
$pass = "********";

$this = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);

Comment: @Extelliqent OK, just rename `$this` to `$db` in **both** files and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @DaveRandom. It didn't give any error this time but nothing saved in database :/

Comment: @Extelliqent You will be getting MySQL syntax errors now because you didn't quote any of the strings in the query. Output the query strings and you will see what I mean.

Comment: This is not even working.. I put the quotes in... $queryone = "INSERT INTO Sublist('scheduled_date', customer_name', kaspersky_status', 'kaspersky_template') VALUES ($kaspersky[0], $customer_name, 'YES', $kaspersky_temp)";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643931/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` in a non object or static method. You should create a new object.

```
$db = new mysqli(......);
$db->query("SELECT ... FROM...");
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured my query is wrong too..