# php call another function in a function

Tags: php, function

im trying to call a function inside another function. based on some research they say using

> $this->

should work. but it gave me

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

```
function addstring($input, $addition_string , $position) {
    $output = substr_replace($input, $addition_string, $position, 0);
    return $output;
}


function test($astring) {
    $output2 = $this->addstring($astring, 'asd', 1);
}
```

to view the rest of my code :

> http://pastebin.com/5ukmpYVB

error :

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in BLA.php on line 48

Comment: *"to view the rest of my code"* --- You have enough rep points to post it.

Comment: just remove `$this->`

Comment: Or better yet, add a class.

Comment: `$this->` implies the current class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643931/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$this-> is needed if you are within a class, if you don't, just call the function by its name:

```
function test($astring) {
    $output2 = addstring($astring, 'asd', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the error mentioned by Nicolas,

```
function test($astring) {
```

has no return value and does not use the parameter by reference, which means, the function is not doing anything but wasting performance.

To demonstrate how you bring the functions into `class context`:

```
class StringHelper
{
    private $output;

    protected function addstring($input, $addition_string , $position) {
        $output = substr_replace($input, $addition_string, $position, 0);
        return $output;
    }

    public function test($astring) {
        $this->output = $this->addstring($astring, 'asd', 1);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOutput() {
        return $this->output;
    }
}


$stringObj = new StringHelper;
echo $stringObj->test('my string')->getOutput();
```